# I can no longer access many onion sites

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-routing, help, error, onionaddress

So recently I have been unable to access some onion sites. At first I thought that just the site I was visiting was down but as I have done more research it seems like half of the sites I try to access wont work. I get the error

Problem loading onionsite Onionsite Not Found

The most likely cause is that the onionsite is offline. Contact the onionsite administrator.

Details: 0xF0 — The requested onion service descriptor can't be found on the hashring and therefore the service is not reachable by the client.

These are V3 site addresses not V2, I have tried mirrors, checking my data and time against the wiki clock, getting a new identity, and a fresh reinstall of the tor browser.

Anyone else having this issue or solved it in the past?

Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed on another device that these onion addresses actually work? Are these official addresses for popular services (DuckDuckGo, Facebook, etc) that you're sure are really online?

Comment: I don't have a clue as to the answer, but I have the same question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Tor binary is too outdated. Just download an expert bundle and use it with a browser you prefer - or compile it by hand from source.

Answer (score 0):

If your inability to access sites is intermittent, it could be because the network is frequently getting DDoS'ed.